# printing an array in Nim using echo

Tags: nim-lang

Following the example here: https://nim-by-example.github.io/arrays/ and I am printing out an array. In the example they print the matrix, but the echo does not work and I get the following error:

```
matrix.nim(20, 7) Error: type mismatch: got (Matrix[2, 2])
but expected one of: 
system.$(x: T)
system.$(x: Enum)
system.$(x: int64)
system.$(x: bool)
system.$(x: char)
system.$(x: float)
system.$(x: string)
system.$(x: seq[T])
system.$(x: int)
system.$(x: uint64)
system.$(x: set[T])
```

I'm assuming this is versioning issue (I have im Compiler Version 0.12.0 installed on Ubuntu - probably not the latest).

However is there a smart way to print entities of any type. Is there a pprint as there is in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$` operator referenced in the error message is Nim's "to string" operator. `echo` expects that such an operator is defined for the passed in type. It just happens that the latest version of the Nim's `system` module doesn't include a definition of `$` for the `array` type.

You can easily fix the code by adding the following definition in your own module:

```
proc `$`[T,R](m: Matrix[T,R]): string =
  result = ""
  for r in countup(1, m.H):
    for c in countup(1, m.W):
      if c != 1: result.add " "
      result.add $m[r][c]

    result.add "\n"
```

This results in the expected output:

```
1 1
1 1
```

The closest thing to an universal printing operator is the Nim's `repr` proc, which tries to return the standard Nim's syntax representation of the values or the `marshal` module, which can encode an arbitrary type in json:

```
var sum = mat1 + mat2

echo sum.repr

import marshal
echo $$sum
```

In this particular example, both options yield the same result:

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]

[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: [Standard implementation](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/system.nim#L2385). It's currently disabled due to some bootstrapping issues.

Comment: echo sum.repr is useful!